# Encoding and Decoding - Custom objects and implementation

Tags: objective-c

I am working on a project where I have various custom objects. These custom objects (some of which work with nested mutable arrays) need to be saved into a file / or files. What would be the best approach to doing so? Should I create a load & save file manager or would it be a better idea to let each object handle that?

Thank you for your time.

-- Steven

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Implement [`NSCoding`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Protocols/NSCoding_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html) protocol for you class:

```
NSString * const kMyArray = @"myString";
NSString * const kMyBool = @"myBool";

- (void)encodeWithCoder:(NSCoder *)coder
{
    [coder encodeObject:_myArray forKey:kMyArray];
    [coder encodeBool:_myBool forKey:kMyBool];
    //...
}

- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)coder
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        _myArray = [coder decodeObjectForKey:kMyArray];
        _myBool = [coder decodeBoolForKey:kMyBool];
        //...
    }
    return self;
}
```

Which allows you to save and load data with [`NSKeyedArchiver`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSKeyedArchiver_Class/Reference/Reference.html):

```
//saving collection of Class<NSCoding> objects
NSString *documentsDirectory = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES)[0];
NSString *path = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"data.plist"];
BOOL success = [NSKeyedArchiver archiveRootObject:_collection toFile:path];

//loading
NSData *data = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:path];
if (data) _collection = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:data];
```

Comment: Excellent. I initially tried to implement a Load/Save object that followed the NSCoding protocol along with each of the custom objects following that same protocol. However, it turned into a big mess fast. So for now, what I will do is have each object type do its own file saving, as these objects pertain to different parts and can be separated just fine.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to encode and decode objects you could take a look at NSCoding. It's a straight forward approach.

Take a look in the documentation : https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Protocols/NSCoding_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html
(edited correct link)

I've had issues when updating an iOS version that the stored objects became corrupt. It was around the transition from iOS 4.1 to iOS 4.2.

I stopped using NSCoder and switch to creating a custom file format, which has an underlying JSON file. Now I have more control over file versioning and fixes can be easily made because it's all about interpreting your own data file.

Answer (score 0):

You can manually create a plist file (Suppose **Config.plist** is the name of the plist) in your app bundle and after copying it into Document directory, you are able to modify it programmatically.

So look here how to copy your file into Document Directory :
First of all define two macros :

```
#define DOCUMENT_DIR        [NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Documents"]
#define PLIST_SETTINGS      [DOCUMENT_DIR stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Config.plist"]
```

After that -

```
 NSString *configPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Config" ofType:@"plist"];
[self copyIfNeededFrom:configPath To:PLIST_SETTINGS];
 NSMutableArray* mArrObjects = [NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:obj1,obj2,obj3, nil];
[mArrObjects writeToFile:PLIST_SETTINGS atomically:YES];
[mArrObjects release];
```

Now give the definition of **copyIfNeededFrom: to:**

```
- (BOOL)copyIfNeededFrom:(NSString *)sourcePath To:(NSString *)destinationPath
{
NSError *error = noErr;
if(![[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:destinationPath])
{
    [[NSFileManager defaultManager] copyItemAtPath:sourcePath toPath:destinationPath error:&error];
}
if(noErr)
    return YES;
else
    return NO;
}
```

Hope it works for you.
Cheers!!!